# Url not resolve on release apk but resovle on debug

Tags: flutter

My app have to reach a rocket.chat server. When I use VSCode in debug mode is working.
But when I build the app publish in beta version and I test it on the same phone I have the error

> SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'xxx.xxxx.xxx' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

I checked the AndroidManifest.xml and I have 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

I cannot understand why is working on debug but not on release.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. 
There are multiple `AndroidManifest.xml`

This file is use to build release app and I doesn't have the Internet permission
`android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`